# Auto Position Window - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I created some window, disabled border and set SizeToContent="Height".

xaml:

```
<Window Title="info" Width="350" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" Opacity="1" Background="{x:Null}" AllowsTransparency="True" SizeToContent="Height">
   <Grid>
     <StackPanel Name="maingrid" Background="AliceBlue">
     </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I open this window I position it in right bottom screen:

```
private void setposition()
{
   var primaryMonitorArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
   this.Left = primaryMonitorArea.Right - this.Width;
   this.Top = primaryMonitorArea.Bottom - this.Height;
}
```

Sometimes I try to add children to **maingrid**, and reposition it again because Height has been changed:

```
Border brd = new Border();
DockPanel.SetDock(brd, Dock.Top);
brd.Margin =new System.Windows.Thickness(0,5,0,0);
DockPanel dpanel = new DockPanel();
System.Windows.Controls.Label header = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
header.Content = "test";
DockPanel.SetDock(header, Dock.Top);
dpanel.Children.Add(header);
brd.Child = dpanel;
maingrid.Children.Add(brd);
setposition();
System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
tmer.Tick += (sender, e) => timertick(brd, tmer);
tmer.Interval = 5 * 1000;
tmer.Enabled = true;
```

After that the window position is positioned randomly in vertical plane. After 5 seconds, I destroyed its border and tried repositioning the window

```
private void timertick(Border brd, System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer)
{
  maingrid.Children.Remove(brd);
  timer.Enabled = false;
  setposition();
  timer.Dispose();         
}
```

and again vertical position has some strange value.

Position on screen:

[image: Position on screen]

Comment: In WPF you must either wait for render or force layouting (by calling measure/arrange yourself) before new sizes are available. Btw, use `DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: How I can wait when window has render?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is the problem (what is exactly wrong?), it was my nuts comment. But if that's the right guess, then just `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => methodToRunAfterRender, DispatcherPriority.Render)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify more precisely what you expect and try to verbalize your question?

If you are trying to position your windows why not use **WindowStartupLocation**?

> Setting WindowStartupLocation to Manual causes a window to be positioned according to its Left and Top property values. If either the Left or Top properties aren't specified, their values are determined by Windows.
>   Setting CenterScreen causes a window to be positioned in the center of the screen that contains the mouse cursor.
>
> Setting WindowStartupLocation to CenterOwner causes a window to be
>   positioned in the center of its owner window (see Owner), if
>   specified. The owner window can be either another WPF window or a
>   non-WPF window.

[MSDN source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx)

Comment: Have you seen this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330446/how-to-know-when-a-control-or-window-has-been-rendered-drawn-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you call `setposition();` the window size is not yet actualized, the simplest thing to get actual size is to wait for render by putting action into dispatcher queue.

Consider this example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (s, e) => Title = $"{ActualHeight}"; // 39
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), IsEnabled = true };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "123", Width = 200, Height = 20 });
        Title = $"{ActualHeight}"; // 39, 59, 79 ... wrong
        // below is correct way, displays 59, 79 ...
        //Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Title = $"{ActualHeight}", DispatcherPriority.Render);
    };
}
```

here I have window which sizes to content and have `stackPanel`.

```
<Window SizeToContent="Height" Width="200" ...>
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel" />
</Window>
```

The timer adds new `TextBlock` to it every second.

Now, if I try to update `Title` like this, then `ActualHeight` is still old one, after first update the first value is `39` and this is wrong (it should be `20 + 39 = 59`). This happens because adding child doesn't cause immediate recalculation of everything and render. No. Instead all such actions (measure, arrange and render) are queued via dispatcher and *occurs some time later*. That's how WPF works.

To fix the problem I can simply tell *"please do it after render"*:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ..., DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, that maingrid.ActualHeight have actual height before window has been render, and do that:

```
this.Top = primaryMonitorArea.Bottom - maingrid.ActualHeight;
```

Its work fine.